# Listing all plans by group using microsoft graph API

Tags: ms-office, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am receiving access denied when trying to access the plans by group in beta using the endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/plans.
I use clientsecret and clientId and I granted my application all required permissions on Azure AD as well as consented by admin. Is there a limitation? is this feature not available using app only permissions?

Comment: Found the answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166344/problems-accessing-office-365-planner-data-using-graph-api-by-application-due

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your app is running on a back-end server (not in a browser), do not forget to add `offline_access` scope (in addition to `Group.Read.All` and `Group.ReadWrite.All`).

Having these scopes, I can successfully access *Plans* of *Unified group* using query like this:

```
/beta/plans?$filter=owner eq '{groupId}'
```

Comment: Thanks, is this for V2 authentication? I am using V1 authentication ClientCrediential ,AuthenticationContext I am not using any scopes and I am using only the permissions at Azure AD for Graph.

Comment: also I am using app only permissions not delegated as this will run without user interactions, does this apply?

Comment: Never tried with V1. I am using V2 with app only permissions. Initially I am going through oauth2 trust process, while submitting clientId, clientSecret, and scopes. It provides me with access code. This code then is used to get Refresh Token and Access Token. I have working authentication code in Nodejs if you are interested.