# ASP.Net Getting redirected to login page

Tags: asp.net, forms, webforms

I've a ASP.Net 4.5.2 Webforms Website that was running just fine. Since last two days, I `401 Unauthorized` for all the static files. I've not made any changes to the website code. I tried re-installing IIS but still no success (IIS 10/Win10)

Here is the `authentication` block from my root `web.config`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/l/login" timeout="28400" />
</authentication>
```

[image]

Comment: I solved the issue by following the this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23666257/851598

Answer (score 0):

please open windows file explorer, add "Authenticated Users" to application folder security setting.