# .net IIS form authentication always denies access even with a properly configured web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis

i have a test virtual environment setup for a windows 2012 R2 IIS web server and a windows DC controller for DNS etc..  i'm working off the windows 2012 R2 IIS web server called testweb.. i have a simple visual studio 2019 web form project running off testweb. it's basically just the initial .net web form project you start with. i created a login.aspx and have configured my web.config file, i have used several tutorials i found online such as

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fa9d0d/forms-authentication-in-Asp-Net/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/301240/how-to-implement-forms-based-authentication-in-your-asp-net-applicatio

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoRWKBbc6QI&t=207s , a video to show the same

i have set my website and the application to allow forms authentication

[image: IIS website config]

[image]

also the following security is installed for IIS

[image]

my webconfig is the default from the initial project with just these added lines

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx"> 
       <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">  
           <user name="user1" password="password1"/>  
           <user name="user2" password="password2" />  
       </credentials>
     </forms>
  </authentication>


<authorization>
     <deny users ="?" />
     <allow users = "*" />  
  </authorization>
```

If i attempt to hit the published site i get the following:

[image]

If i remove the lines :

```
<authorization>
     <deny users ="?" />
     <allow users = "*" />  
  </authorization>
```

Then i can hit http://testweb/testlogin/ and it brings up Default.aspx perfectly fine !! so i'm scratching my head , well banging my head, trying to figure out what is not set properly or what am i missing ?? i've gone over every tutorial online. even if i only have deny users ? in web.config it still doesn't work.

```
 <authorization>
     <deny users ="?" />
  </authorization>
```

Any help appreciated , again just trying to understand how to get forms authentication working in a test env and go from there.. but seems like as soon as add Auth to deny anonymous users with ? it's just denying me all around. my exceptions are that i should be getting my login.aspx page but just isn't working.

Current web.config based on replies/comments:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>

  <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx"> 
       <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">  
           <user name="user1" password="password1"/>  
           <user name="user2" password="password2" />  
       </credentials>
     </forms>
  </authentication>

  <authorization>
     <deny users ="?" />
  </authorization>

  </system.web>

  <location path="login.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web> 
  </location>


  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> 
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930"/>
      </dependentAssembly>      
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

my folder that contains my test website has defaultapp pool set and the defaultapp pool user has read/execute, that was not set before but i set it and it didn't make any differences see below image

[image]

**UPDATE and FIX***

so i finally found this post https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2920a4e2-775a-4aa7-bfff-4931fa0a4e9a/azure-website-forms-authentication-issue?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview
and if followed it and added a 2nd path statement for just login without the .aspx then it worked!! i was able to hit my login.aspx page fine.

so my final working Web.config looks like this or the snips of code for form auth.

```
 <system.web>

<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx"> 
       <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">  
           <user name="user1" password="password1"/>  
           <user name="user2" password="password2"/>  
       </credentials>
     </forms>
  </authentication>

  <authorization>
     <deny users ="?" />
  </authorization>

  </system.web>

  <location path="login.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web> 
  </location>

  <location path="login">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users ="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Read IIS log files to see if you hit 401.3 or other substatus code, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: if i debug it from VStudio my browser states "Server Error in '/' Application".. then 401.2

Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow unauthenticated users access to your login page.

Try adding this to the web.config:

```
<location path="login.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
        <allow users ="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: thanks. i saw that too on some google'ing around and thought i tried it before. i re-instated that code too and still getting the 401.2, here is what the web.config looks like now, see my updated edits.. and my login.aspx and Default.aspx are all in the root of my project and site they are not in any other dir

Comment: The only other thing I can think to check is that the identity of the web site's application pool has permissions on the file system folder that contains your web site.  Also, there is this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162430/401-unauthorized-on-a-directory

Comment: thx i went and change that from "specific user" set to IUSR to "application pool identity" then i went and made sure the default app pool user had read and execute on the folder, i also set this as the site level as well as the testlogin app level. see my update to original post with image.. also remember i'm never ever getting even my login.aspx page to even attempt to login :(, it just immediately denies me access .

Comment: holy crap! i figured it out, via this post 

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2920a4e2-775a-4aa7-bfff-4931fa0a4e9a/azure-website-forms-authentication-issue?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

so i had to add a location path for "login.aspx" and for "login" the filename without the .aspx extension :| why i don't know... i updated my post