# The Function App/GetSPANList returns 401 error on server. C# asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

The below method returns `401` error on server. As I don't see any errors in this. Please suggest why its coming as 401 error

```js
function loadSPANByMZ() {
    try {
        showLoading();
        var OperationType = "";
        if (R4GStateSelected != "Select") {
            if ($(mzoneid).val() != "Select") {
                if ($(activitytypeid).val() != "Select") {
                    //call CurrentGroupName UMS variable
                    var UserType = CurrentGroupName;
                    var SpanType = $(spantypeid + ' option:selected').val().toUpperCase();
                    var MZone = $(mzoneid + ' option:selected').val();
                    OperationType = $(activitytypeid + ' option:selected').val();
                    var Values = { "USERTYPE": UserType, "SPANTYPE": SpanType, "MZONE": MZone, "OPERATIONTYPE": OperationType.toUpperCase() };
                    //$(gridSpanlisttable).empty();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: AppConfig.PrefixURL + "App/GetSPANList",
                        data: JSON.stringify(Values),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: false,
                        success: function (response) {                            
                            displaySpanList(response, SpanType, MZone, OperationType);
                            //hideLoading();
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            hideLoading();
                            $(dataContent).hide();
                        },
                        complete : function(response)
                        {
                            hideLoading();
                            
                }

                });
        }
        
        }
    }

//},
       
} 
catch (e) {
    hideLoading();
    $(dataContent).show();
}

}
```

Comment: 401 means "Unauthorized". How is the .net API authenticating and authorizing the Ajax requests? Cookie? Token? Has the API controller or the POST method an [Authorize] attribute? The request is reaching the server, but it returns Unauthorized, so your client (JS) code may be OK, except for the credentials / authorization issue.

Comment: @Pepelui360: yes we are using POST method. but we are not adding any credentials

Comment: If the API requires authentication or authorization, you MUST pass some kind of credentials / token to the server. How are users authenticating? If it uses cookies to mantain user session, usually cookies are sent automatically in Ajax calls. To verify if this is a authorization Issue, you can try adding [AllowAnonymous] attribute to Post method in controller. Warning: this could let anyone call this API method, not only your client application.

Comment: we are authenticating by `Windows authentication`

Comment: @Pepelui360 will this answer by **siddharta** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162430/401-unauthorized-on-a-directory work ?