# How to redirect to login page in ASP.NET Core 6 web app with Angular frontend?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-6.0

I developed an ASP.NET Core 6 based web application which uses Angular for the frontend.
I also implemented a custom authentication handler (based on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler) because I need to authenticate against a custom 3rd party API in this application. Here is how the application is currently initialized:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<DatabaseContextName>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CustomAuthDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddScheme<CustomAuthSchemeOptions, CustomAuthHandler>(
        CustomAuthDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
});

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

// Backend-Routes for the treatment of 404-Errors
app.Map("api/{**slug}", HandleApiFallback);

// Fallback-Route to the Frontend
app.MapFallbackToFile("{**slug}", "index.html");

app.Run();

static Task HandleApiFallback(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

In the Angular frontend I already have a `HttpInterceptor` in place to redirect to the login page if the user is no longer authenticated. While this currently works just fine when hosting the app on Kestrel, the redirect does not work at all while hosting the app on an IIS webserver.

Not only does the IIS webserver ignore my session timeout of 8 hours as configured in `builder.Services.AddSession()` and lets the session expire much quicker (it seems to expire after less than a few minutes already), but it also seems to block any http requests entirely as soon as the session expired. This results in a blank page being shown to the user after refreshing the site (because IIS returns a HTTP 401 error), instead of redirecting to the login page.

How can I configure the application to use the correct session timeout and also fix the redirect to the login page after the session expired in IIS?

I already found some suggestions such as adding `.AddCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/login")` after `builder.Services.AddAuthentication()` or adding `builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/login")`
but none of those worked for me so far.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout?view=netframework-4.8) add Session timeout in Web.config. Is the redirect not working all the time? You could use [FRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing) to generate logs for more detailed redirect error information.

Comment: @TengFeiXie I already tried changing this setting and even after restarting the site, the application pool or even the entire IIS, it did not make any difference. Changing the application pool recycle timeout also did not make a difference. The frontend still starts receiving 401 errors for requests after ~20 minutes. I do not understand what is happening here.

Comment: About 401 error, don't worry. It is usually due to authentication issues. You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162430/401-unauthorized-on-a-directory). I suggest you use FRT to see what happens during redirection.

Comment: Thanks! The suggestion from your linked answer works, but only partially. When the session expired and I try to refresh the entire page, I still get a 401 error and a blank page. How can I configure it to redirect to the login page instead?

Comment: Additionally, I have already enabled FRT but that only confirmed what I already found out. It shows a warning in step 52 (MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS) with the following information:
ModuleName: AspNetCoreModuleV2, Notification: EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER, HttpStatus: 401, HttpReason: Unauthorized, HttpSubStatus: 0, ErrorCode: Der Vorgang wurde erfolgreich beendet. (0x0). I already know that the IIS returns a 401 which causes the browser to show a blank page, but why does Kestrel not do this while debugging and how do I fix this?

Comment: You need to correct your middleware order, check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#order) for middleware order. `app.UseSession();` after `app.UseAuthorization();` as per documentation.

Comment: @HardikSolanki I already tried this in the meanwhile but without success. I cannot place `app.UseSession()` after `app.UseAuthorization()` because it will break my entire authentication process which is based on data stored inside the session. See my answer below for how I actually solved this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further troubleshooting and with the help of several people I was able to finally solve this problem.

It turns out that the fallback I added via `MapFallbackToFile` did not work properly when not authenticated. After changing this line to `app.MapFallbackToFile("{**slug}", "index.html").AllowAnonymous()`, everything seems to work fine. No idea if this is the proper solution, but it works.